# Finding factorial of a number in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Following is my code :

```
data segment
num db 05h
fact db 02h
data ends
code segment
assume cs:code, ds:data
start: mov dx,data
mov ds,dx
mov al,01h
mov bl,num
inc bl
call prc
prc proc
imul fact
inc fact
cmp fact,bl
jz endproc
call prc
endproc: mov fact,al
ret
prc endp
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

I am aware that the program isn't correct. Here are the questions I have about this (I am trying to learn procedures) :

1. To end a procedure, do we write directly `endp` *or* `[name] endp` (multiple books are giving me multiple answers)
2. When it reaches the multiplication of 4*6, `imul` returns 18 in `AL`? How?
3. After `ret` statement, the program jumps to the previous statement, not the statement after procedure end

And help is appreciated!

Comment: 1) Use `[name] endp` if supported - more readable. 2) Consult the Intel Manual 2 (Google for it) for instructions reference. 3) That's why it's called `ret`urn - See point 2.

Comment: To (2), seems lik the output is in hexadecimal.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I appreciate the help though I seriously do not have the time to go through any more books, I have 2 exams tomorrow and I need to study for the next one. Can you tell me what the problem is here for point 2 and 3?

Comment: @fuz Oh my god ain't I stupid. Thanks! Do you know how can I rectify problem 3?

Comment: @MihirKandoi "problem 3" is not a problem. It's doing what it's supposed to. Move the code that follows the procedure so that it instead follows the first call point. Hmm, I will elaborate in an answer.

Comment: about 3) the `proc/endp` directives are not doing anything much, in high-level languages the compiler will put procedure code "aside" out of way of main code, but in assembly that `proc/endp` is just source decoration to make it easier to read for human. The code is still assembled sequentially into memory. So after your `call prc` the next instruction in memory is `imul fact`, and that's where the `ret` will "return". You should see that also in debugger, that after the "call" line the procedure code follows. You have to put it aside by hand in the source, and make real code to follow call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To end a procedure, do we write directly endp or [name] endp

Try it and see... I believe either will work. Including the name improves clarity.

> When it reaches the multiplication of 4*6, imul returns 18 in al? how?

Because 4 times 6 is 24 (in decimal) which is 18 in hexadecimal.

> After ret statement, the program jumps to the previous statement, not the statement after procedure end

`ret` causes the execution to continue from the point at which the procedure was called. Since your procedure calls itself - i.e. it *recurses* - the ret instruction could cause it to return to the line just before the `ret` instruction simply because the corresponding `call` is the line before that. Probably, that (second) `call` instruction should really be a `jmp` instruction, to return to the start of the procedure without recursing. Then, the `ret` will always return to the instruction after the original `call`.

At that point, however, you have another problem. Since you have the procedure immediately after the call point, the `ret` instruction will cause execution to resume at the beginning of the procedure; when it reaches `ret` again your program will likely crash. The code you have written after the end of the procedure should instead be moved so that it is after the call point (i.e. it should be between the call point and the procedure).

Answer (score 0):

;The following program is used to find the factorial of a number in 8086 assembly
include emu8086.inc

```
org 100h


 call input
 call check
 call factorial
ret

input proc
  lea dx,msg
  mov ah,9  
  int 21h  ;to print the string

  mov ah,1
  int 21h    ;input from the user one character
  sub al,30h ;to change the ascii into our decimal number
  mov ch,al

  mov ah,1
  int 21h
  sub al,30h
  mov cl,al
  print '!'
 ret
  input endp

check proc
    cmp ch,0  ;ch-0
    je fact ;if they are equal jump to the factorial

    lea dx,msg2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
     hlt
ret 
 check endp

fact: 
factorial proc
    lea dx,msg1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov ax,1 ;initialize
label:
    cmp cx,0
    je quit
    mul cx ;ax=ax*cx
    loop label
quit: 
  call print_num_uns ;to print the number found in ax register
ends   
factorial endp

mov ah,4ch    ;to return control to the operating system
int 21h 

msg db 'Enter the number: $'
msg1 db 10,13,'The factorial is: $'                                  
msg2 db 10,13,'The factorial is out of bound,sorry we can not help you $'
define_print_num_uns

end
```